# Python mimetypes on Windows missing some extensions

Tags: python, windows, mime-types

I want `mimetypes` library to return mimetype from file name. For example:

```py
>>> mimetypes.types_map['.docx']
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
```

But, currently I got an exception:

```py
>>> mimetypes.types_map['.docx']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '.docx'
```

Also I tried `guess_type` func:

```py
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('.docx')
(None, None)
```

---

Full code:

```py
import mimetypes
mimetypes.init()
mimetypes.types_map['.docx']  # throws an Exception
mimetypes.guess_type('.docx')  # returns (None, None)
```

---

Python: 3.8.10

Windows 10 build ver. 19044.2006

On my system I got installed Ubuntu WSL 2. When executing my **Full code** there: no exceptions are raised and mimetype returns as excepted (also python 3.8.10)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a "name" before dot.

```
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('.docx')
(None, None)
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('filename.docx')
('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', None)
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html

Comment: Hi. Thx for answer. Unfortunately, same output:
`>>> mimetypes.guess_type('test.docx')  (None, None)`

Comment: try this:

`mimetypes.guess_all_extensions("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")`

Comment: You have docx mapping type in your OS?
docx is not in the python mimetype module by default. [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/mimetypes.py#L384)

Comment: From `guess_all_extensions` an empty list returned.

How could I check `docx` mapping? Once I looked inside `regedit` and found `.docx` there, but is this what I'm looking for?

Comment: Check on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` inside `regedit`. Is the place where python find for mimetypes. See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/mimetypes.py#L231) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/mimetypes.py#L256)

Comment: Yeah, during debug I stepped into library code. I found there `.docx` extension with value `Word.Document.12`

Comment: One question, your OS know who is .docx? You have a office software installed ?

Comment: Yes. I can open office files freely

Comment: I think regedit keys had been removed by some other app, so I would reinstall office package later. I'll leave feedback after.

Answer (score 0):

Repair of Office package via Control Panel updated `regedit` and added missing ContentType records.

I chose offline mode during the repair.